# How to avoid pre-selection of first list-item

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbon-control

I'm filling a Ribbon Gallery (`Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGallery`) with items at runtime with c#. Now when I open the gallery for the first time, the first item of the list is always pre-selected and thus can't be clicked before selecting one of the other items. I don't want to disable the `ShowItemSelection` attribute permanently, but before choosing a value, there shouldn't be a selection.

Is there any way to realize this?

I already tried to set the `SelectedItemIndex` to -1 as well as setting the `SelectedItem` attribute to `null`, but neither changed anything.

Long story short:
None of the items of the ribbon gallery should be pre-selected when opening it the first time.

Any clues please?

Comment: `By default, the first RibbonDropDownItem in the Items collection is selected`, more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbongallery.selecteditem?view=vsto-2017). Where are you trying to set the `SelectedItemIndex` or `SelectedItem`? Also, if the `Items` collection has at least one member in it, its guaranteed to **not be null** (the SelectedItem)... One solution and or possibility is to add a blank item to the collection at the beginning...

Comment: You can do this with a `DropDown` by returning -1 as the index. Could be an alternative.

Comment: Add a blank Item with a know value that you have set so that if selected you can catch that and say to do nothing. Select this value by default and then present the rest of your list options for selection.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I set the `SelectedItem|Index` inside the `RibbonGallery_Open` method right after filling the list ... the blank item is not an option because I'm using the index later in the code, so I don't want to start shifting it around

Comment: @Camp but if I could just say 'do nothing' this would already solve my problem ... And afaik you can't make items invisible inside the gallery, so I don't quite get what you're trying to tell me

Comment: Do nothing could be relative you could have it do nothing to affect anything on the page. Have it change a hidden value from 1 to 0 or something like that. Give it a task that does nothing to your application and does not interfere with any other pieces.

Comment: @Camp but if I did that, I would have a nonsense item in my list that still would be displayed. That's not a solution for me